# Wrong parameter binding when using named queries with optional parameters in EclipseLink

Tags: jpa, oracle11g, eclipselink, jpql

I'm trying to do a database lookup using JPA with EclipseLink. My database is Oracle 11.2.0. I have the following entity classes defined:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BS_PROVIDERS")
public class BsProvider {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "GUID")
    private String guid;
    public String getGuid() { return guid; }
    public void setGuid(String guid) { this.guid = guid; }

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CP_PROVIDERS")
public class CpProvider{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "GUID")
    private String guid;
    public String getGuid() { return guid; }
    public void setGuid(String guid) { this.guid = guid; }

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

}

@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
        name = Catalog.FIND_BY_CPP_AND_BSP,
        query = "select c from Catalog c where (c.cpProvider = :cpProvider) and ( (:bsProvider IS NULL) or (c.bsProvider = :bsProvider))"
        )
})
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATALOGS")
public class Catalog {

    public static final String FIND_BY_CPP_AND_BSP = "Catalog.findByCppAndBsp";
    public static final String CP_PROVIDER_PARAM = "cpProvider";
    public static final String BS_PROVIDER_PARAM = "bsProvider";

    @Id
    @Column(name = "GUID")
    private String guid;
    public String getGuid() { return guid; }
    public void setGuid(String guid) { this.guid = guid; }

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName() { this.name = name; }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CPP_GUID")
    private CpProvider cpProvider;
    public CpProvider getCpProvider() { return cpProvider; }
    public void setCpProvider(CpProvider cpProvider) { this.cpProvider = cpProvider; }

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "BSP_GUIG")
    private BsProvider bsProvider;
    public BsProvider getBsProvider() { return bsProvider; }
    public void setBsProvider(BsProvider bsProvider) { this.bsProvider = bsProvider; }

}
```

Code that creates the query and sets the parameters:

```
TypedQuery<Catalog> catalogQuery = em.createNamedQuery(Catalog.FIND_BY_CPP_AND_BSP, Catalog.class);
catalogQuery.setParameter(Catalog.CP_PROVIDER_PARAM, cpProvider);
catalogQuery.setParameter(Catalog.BS_PROVIDER_PARAM, bsProvider);
List<Catalog> catalogList = catalogQuery.getResultList();
```

When the variable bsProvider is NULL, all parameters are registerd are registerd correctly according to the EclipseLink log:

```
    SELECT GUID, NAME, BSP_GUIG, CPP_GUID FROM CATALOGS WHERE ((CPP_GUID = ?) AND ((? IS NULL) OR (BSP_GUIG = ?)))
        bind => [18EC0EDB-21A4-4845-960A-D5D2BDAC7B87, null, null]
```

Otherwise when the variable bsProvider refers to an existing entity I get the following exception:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
Error Code: 17004
Call: SELECT GUID, NAME, BSP_GUIG, CPP_GUID FROM CATALOGS WHERE ((CPP_GUID = ?) AND ((? IS NULL) OR (BSP_GUIG = ?)))
    bind => [18EC0EDB-21A4-4845-960A-D5D2BDAC7B87, com.bssys.ebpp.dbaccess.model.BsProvider@5dbbe8df, 44E8F4BF-CFDC-49DB-AB0B-718C72D6B4EF]
```

As you can see the first and the third parameters are bound correctly (they are replaced by the primary key values), but the second is not. What's the reason of such a strange behavior?

Comment: You haven't shown the named query, but it looks like the probable cause is that there is no mapping to use in the query to determine what type to use for the parameter.  This forces eclipselink to serialize the object since it can't determine what you want to do with it.

Comment: The named query is provided in the Catalog class definition (see the @NamedQueries annotation).
It is strange because the third parameter is bound correctly: 44E8F4BF-CFDC-49DB-AB0B-718C72D6B4EF.

Comment: That's not strange - the third parameter is a comparison to c.bsProvider, so it is required to deal with an entity.  The second parameter is just an object, so the provider doesn't know what you want to do with it and so serialized it.  Regardless, aren't you better off doing the null check in code and executing a different named query?

Comment: Could you please provide a documentation reference on how EclipseLink deals with named parameters in such situations? I could accept the answer then.

Comment: I can't.  JPA doesn't say how to handle isNull, so providers are allowed to pass what they want.  Since you are passing an object, it wouldn't be correct to pick a specific field out of that object, since that field could be null even if the object is not.  Can your database not handle the serialized object?